# How can I rotate this SVG element correctly?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been attempting to create a gauge with a range of 0 - 100. I have created this SVG element in Sketch and now I'm trying to get the rotation to work for the black needle.

To do this, I have tried playing around with `transform-origin` and `transform: rotate()` but I can't seem to get it to rotate like seen in the `.gif` as it always seems to get cut off. I have added a JS range slider for your convenience to demonstrate the issue. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoLrvm) is also a codepen to experiment.

Could you help me achieve the desired result as seen in the gif?

[image]

```js
$('#percent').on('change', function() {
  $('#needle').css('transform', 'translate(175px, 19px) rotate(' + percentToDegrees($(this).val()) + 'deg)')
})

function percentToDegrees(percent) {
  var degrees = -90;
  var inc = 1.8;
  return degrees += (percent * inc);
}
```

```css
#needle {
  transform-origin: 0% bottom;
  transform: translate(175px, 19px) rotate(0);
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" height="177px" viewBox="0 0 385 177" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-15.000000, -224.000000)">
            <g id="Group" transform="translate(15.000000, 220.000000)">
                <g id="guage">
                    <path d="M84.8041871,178.856781 L84.8041871,179.169281 L25,179.169281 L25,178.669281 C25,119.519295 57.1931907,67.8894771 105.011512,40.3501901 L135,92.2989954 C105.009619,109.483749 84.8041871,141.810321 84.8041871,178.856781 Z" id="red" fill="#BD3632"></path>
                    <path d="M235.050803,92.4864742 C205.21439,75.1028089 167.169843,73.7652453 135.133157,92.2884751 L134.862916,92.4447251 L105,40.6455806 L105.432385,40.3955806 C156.58355,10.8205878 217.307001,12.8896752 265,40.5376689 L235.050803,92.4864742 L235.050803,92.4864742 Z" id="yellow" fill="#EEAF30"></path>
                    <path d="M235,92.2989954 L264.988488,40.3501901 C312.806809,67.8894771 345,119.519295 345,178.669281 L345,179.169281 L285.195813,179.169281 L285.195813,178.856781 C285.195813,141.810321 264.990381,109.483749 235,92.2989954 L235,92.2989954 Z" id="green" fill="#008542"></path>
                    <text id="100%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="15" fill="#000000">
                        <tspan x="350" y="180">100%</tspan>
                    </text>
                    <text id="50%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" fill="#000000">
                        <tspan x="171" y="14">50%</tspan>
                    </text>
                    <text id="0%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" fill="#000000">
                        <tspan x="0" y="178">0%</tspan>
                    </text>
                </g>
                <g id="needle" transform="translate(175.000000, 19.000000)">
                    <polygon id="Triangle" fill="#3C3C3B" points="10 0 15 162 5 162"></polygon>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<input type="range" id="percent" value="50" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: is [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoEpox), what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: One more demo [here](https://hongkiat.github.io/svg-meter-gauge/)

Comment: pretty cool though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider `transform-box:fill-box;` then make the origin `bottom center` and increase the viewbox a little to avoid the cut. I have also moved the rotation to the polygon and kept the translation on the `g` element.

```js
$('#percent').on('change', function() {
  $('#triangle').css('transform', 'rotate(' + percentToDegrees($(this).val()) + 'deg)')
})

function percentToDegrees(percent) {
  var degrees = -90;
  var inc = 1.8;
  return degrees += (percent * inc);
}
```

```css
#triangle {
  transform-origin:center bottom;
  transform-box:fill-box;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" height="177px" viewBox="0 0 385 185" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-15.000000, -224.000000)">
            <g id="Group" transform="translate(15.000000, 220.000000)">
                <g id="guage">
                    <path d="M84.8041871,178.856781 L84.8041871,179.169281 L25,179.169281 L25,178.669281 C25,119.519295 57.1931907,67.8894771 105.011512,40.3501901 L135,92.2989954 C105.009619,109.483749 84.8041871,141.810321 84.8041871,178.856781 Z" id="red" fill="#BD3632"></path>
                    <path d="M235.050803,92.4864742 C205.21439,75.1028089 167.169843,73.7652453 135.133157,92.2884751 L134.862916,92.4447251 L105,40.6455806 L105.432385,40.3955806 C156.58355,10.8205878 217.307001,12.8896752 265,40.5376689 L235.050803,92.4864742 L235.050803,92.4864742 Z" id="yellow" fill="#EEAF30"></path>
                    <path d="M235,92.2989954 L264.988488,40.3501901 C312.806809,67.8894771 345,119.519295 345,178.669281 L345,179.169281 L285.195813,179.169281 L285.195813,178.856781 C285.195813,141.810321 264.990381,109.483749 235,92.2989954 L235,92.2989954 Z" id="green" fill="#008542"></path>
                    <text id="100%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="15" fill="#000000">
                        <tspan x="350" y="180">100%</tspan>
                    </text>
                    <text id="50%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" fill="#000000">
                        <tspan x="171" y="14">50%</tspan>
                    </text>
                    <text id="0%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" fill="#000000">
                        <tspan x="0" y="178">0%</tspan>
                    </text>
                </g>
                <g id="needle" transform="translate(175.000000, 18.000000)">
                    <polygon id="triangle" fill="#3C3C3B" points="10 0 15 162 5 162"></polygon>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<input type="range" id="percent" value="50" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: Just be aware that `transform-box` only works on recent versions of some browsers.  If you want a more compatible solution, you might want to consider @Kaiido's solution that uses absolute coordinates in the `transform-origin`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest is probably to do it all with SVG, simply setting your element's [`transform` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) instead of its css `style`.

All you need is to set the second and third values of the `rotate(angle, origin_x, origin_y)` SVG transform method.

```js
$('#percent').on('input', function() {
  $('#needle').attr('transform', 'translate(175, 19) ' +
    'rotate(' + percentToDegrees($(this).val()) + ', 10, 162)')
})

function percentToDegrees(percent) {
  var degrees = -90;
  var inc = 1.8;
  return degrees += (percent * inc);
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" height="177px" viewBox="0 0 385 177" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-15.000000, -224.000000)">
      <g id="Group" transform="translate(15.000000, 220.000000)">
        <g id="guage">
          <path d="M84.8041871,178.856781 L84.8041871,179.169281 L25,179.169281 L25,178.669281 C25,119.519295 57.1931907,67.8894771 105.011512,40.3501901 L135,92.2989954 C105.009619,109.483749 84.8041871,141.810321 84.8041871,178.856781 Z" id="red" fill="#BD3632"></path>
          <path d="M235.050803,92.4864742 C205.21439,75.1028089 167.169843,73.7652453 135.133157,92.2884751 L134.862916,92.4447251 L105,40.6455806 L105.432385,40.3955806 C156.58355,10.8205878 217.307001,12.8896752 265,40.5376689 L235.050803,92.4864742 L235.050803,92.4864742 Z" id="yellow" fill="#EEAF30"></path>
          <path d="M235,92.2989954 L264.988488,40.3501901 C312.806809,67.8894771 345,119.519295 345,178.669281 L345,179.169281 L285.195813,179.169281 L285.195813,178.856781 C285.195813,141.810321 264.990381,109.483749 235,92.2989954 L235,92.2989954 Z" id="green" fill="#008542"></path>
          <text id="100%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="15" fill="#000000">
            <tspan x="350" y="180">100%</tspan>
          </text>
          <text id="50%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" fill="#000000">
            <tspan x="171" y="14">50%</tspan>
          </text>
          <text id="0%" font-family="Omnes-Regular, Omnes" font-size="15" font-weight="normal" fill="#000000">
            <tspan x="0" y="178">0%</tspan>
          </text>
        </g>
        <g id="needle" transform="translate(175.000000, 19.000000)">
            <polygon id="Triangle" fill="#3C3C3B" points="10 0 15 162 5 162"></polygon>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<input type="range" id="percent" value="50" min="0" max="100">
```

You'll even win in browser compat ;-)

And note that this could be all simplified to:

```js
$('#percent').on('input', function() {
  $('#Triangle')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + percentToDegrees($(this).val()) + ', 10, 162)')
})

function percentToDegrees(percent) {
  var degrees = -90;
  var inc = 1.8;
  return degrees += (percent * inc);
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
#Page-1 text {
  font-family: Omnes-Regular, Omnes;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" height="177px" viewBox="0 0 385 177" version="1.1">
  <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" fill="none" transform="translate(0, -4)">
    <g id="guage">
      <path d="M84.8041871,178.856781 L84.8041871,179.169281 L25,179.169281 L25,178.669281 C25,119.519295 57.1931907,67.8894771 105.011512,40.3501901 L135,92.2989954 C105.009619,109.483749 84.8041871,141.810321 84.8041871,178.856781 Z" id="red" fill="#BD3632"></path>
      <path d="M235.050803,92.4864742 C205.21439,75.1028089 167.169843,73.7652453 135.133157,92.2884751 L134.862916,92.4447251 L105,40.6455806 L105.432385,40.3955806 C156.58355,10.8205878 217.307001,12.8896752 265,40.5376689 L235.050803,92.4864742 L235.050803,92.4864742 Z" id="yellow" fill="#EEAF30"></path>
      <path d="M235,92.2989954 L264.988488,40.3501901 C312.806809,67.8894771 345,119.519295 345,178.669281 L345,179.169281 L285.195813,179.169281 L285.195813,178.856781 C285.195813,141.810321 264.990381,109.483749 235,92.2989954 L235,92.2989954 Z" id="green" fill="#008542"></path>
      <text id="100%" line-spacing="15">
        <tspan x="350" y="180">100%</tspan>
      </text>
      <text id="50%">
        <tspan x="171" y="14">50%</tspan>
      </text>
      <text id="0%">
        <tspan x="0" y="178">0%</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
    <g id="needle" transform="translate(175.000000, 19.000000)">
      <polygon id="Triangle" fill="#3C3C3B" points="10 0 15 162 5 162"></polygon>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<input type="range" id="percent" value="50" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: You could simplify things by just doing `$('#Triangle').attr('transform', 'rotate(' + percentToDegrees($(this).val()) + ', 10, 162)');`

Comment: @PaulLeBeau sure, OP did apply the transformation on the `<g>` so I thought they wanted it to be transformed, there might be something else to go in there. But you're absolutely right that in the current code, it's unecessarily complicated (like all these nested <g> btw).

Comment: @Kaiido it's just what my Sketch editor output for me. If you have a better markup suggestion, please feel free to update your answer with something more simplistic.

Comment: The only issue with this is that the needle is getting cut off at 0 or 180 degrees

Comment: @GBWDev because that's how your drawing is made. You may want to [make the viewBox a bit bigger](https://jsfiddle.net/mkny2vda/) or to change your drawing so that they do fit in the current one even when the needle is rotated.